# Wordpress dies before add_action (plugins API)

Tags: api, woocommerce, wordpress

My setup is pretty standards, Wordpress + WooCommerce.

My client have a specific process, and for that I had to develop an Restful API in order to create coupon from another website.

The API is working pretty well.

In my API plugin code, I have add an action in order to trigger an email (I use custom email extends from WC_Email)

```
do_action("coupon_code_mail_validation", $params);
```

So, in my WC_Email_Coupon, I've add an trigger like that :

```
add_action( 'coupon_code_mail_validation', array( $this, 'trigger' ));
```

And when I execute the code, my add_action is never called (verified with XDebug and breakpoints).

After some research, I think I found why, I fact, I my API plugin I use this function :

```
public function sniff_requests(){
    global $wp;
    if(isset($wp->query_vars['__api'])){
        $this->handle_request();
        exit;
    }
}
```

And I think It's here that the wordpress dies and never execute the add_action.
How could I load the woocommerce plugin into the API after WP dies ?

(For the plugin I inspired myself from : https://gist.github.com/inspectorfegter/2982319)

Thank you for your help and don't hesitate to ask me if you need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; I had to add:

```
global $woocommerce;
$mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();
```

With lastest version :

```
WC()->mailer();
```